# Tkinter: Too much space between label and button frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Tkinter and I build a little window with different widgets.

My Code looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.master.title("Tkinter Sandbox")
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

       self._create_left_frame()
       self._create_button_bar()
       self._create_label_frame()

    def _create_left_frame(self):
       frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="red")

       tree_view = ttk.Treeview(frame)
       tree_view.column("#0", stretch=tk.NO)
       tree_view.heading("#0", text="Treeview")
       tree_view.pack(fill=tk.Y, expand=1)
       frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)

    def _create_button_bar(self):
       frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="blue")

       button_run_single = tk.Button(frame, text="Button 1")
       button_run_all = tk.Button(frame, text="Button 2")
       button_details = tk.Button(frame, text="Button 3")
       button_run_single.grid(row=0, column=0)
       button_run_all.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(35, 35))
       button_details.grid(row=0, column=2)
       frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)

    def _create_label_frame(self):
       frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="blue")

       name_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Label 1")
       performance_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Label 2")
       name_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
       performance_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
       name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
       name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
       performance_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
       performance_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
       frame.grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Between the three buttons and the label + entry frame is a huge space. I want the button and label + entry frame right under each other, without the huge space but the treeview should also expand vertically over the whole application window.

I think the problem might be my row and column configuration but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Use also a `right_frame` for `_button_bar` and `label_frame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've structured your code makes it hard to see the problem. As a good general rule of thumb, all calls to `grid` or `pack` for widgets within a single parent should be in one place. Otherwise, you create dependencies between functions that are hard to see and understand.

I recommend having each of your helper functions return the frame rather than calling `grid` on the frame. That way you give control to `Application.__init__` for the layout of the main sections of the window.

For example:

```
left_frame = self._create_left_frame()
button_bar = self._create_button_bar()
label_frame = self._create_label_frame()

left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
button_bar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
label_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

I used `pack` here because it requires less code than `grid` for this type of layout. However, if you choose to switch to `grid`, or wish to add more widgets to the root window later, you only have to modify this one function rather than modify the `grid` calls in multiple functions.

Note: this requires that your functions each do `return frame` to pass the frame back to the `__init__` method. You also need to remove `frame.grid` from each of your helper functions.

With just that simple change you end up with the button bar and label/entry combinations at the top of the section on the right. In the following screenshot I changed the background of the button_bar to green so you can see that it fills the top of the right side of the UI.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow that is a really great solution and a very useful tipp. I'll do this in my future projects. Do you know some resources or books where I can find best practices regarding these design patterns?

Comment: Hey Brian. Just one last question. Can you provide the sourcecode for your frame? I want to dig deeper a little bit.

Comment: @NealMcBeal: what do you mean by "the sorucecode for your frame"? What frame are you talking about? The code I used was the code from the question with the changes described in the answer.

Comment: Ah interesting because I changed the code regarding your proposal and I have a different behavior in the Label section with label 1 and 2. They are centered. Do you know why I can't insert a progressbar at the bottom?

Comment: @NealMcBeal: there is nothing preventing you from putting a progressbar at the bottom. If you're using `pack` like in my example, you should pack it to the bottom _before_ packing the left and right frames. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396569/7432

Comment: Wow thank you! The problem was my order. I used the create progressbar function at the end of the window creation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change line

```
self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

to

```
self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

so that the second row takes all the space. Then you need to stick widgets from the label frame to its top by adding sticky parameter to the grid call in `_create_label_frame`:

```
frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the Pack Function since it gives a more open window - its easy to configure. When you use Pack() you can use labels with no text and just spaces to create a spacer, by doing this you won't run into the problem your facing.