# How to stick scrollbar in label tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

this is what i got

[image: this is what i got]

And only when I maximize the window I can see the scroll bar

[image: after increases window]

I want to stick the scrollbar (horizontal and vertical) in treeview. regardless of the window size.

I'm trying to add scrollbar to label with treeview regardless of the window size.
this is my code:

```
def mainGUI():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x300")
    root.title("test")
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    data = [["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"]]


    results_lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Results:")
    results_lf.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=0, sticky='ew')

    resultsLabel = Label(results_lf)
    resultsLabel.pack(fill='x',expand=True, side=LEFT)

    columnsHeader = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    tree = ttk.Treeview(resultsLabel, columns=columnsHeader, show='headings')
    tree.heading('1', text='1')
    tree.heading('2', text='2')
    tree.heading('3', text='3')
    tree.heading('4', text='4')
    tree.heading('5', text='5')
    tree.heading('6', text='6')


    for line in data:
        tree.insert('', tk.END, values=line)
    tree.pack(side=LEFT)

    sb_v = Scrollbar(resultsLabel, orient=VERTICAL)
    sb_v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    sb_h = Scrollbar(resultsLabel, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    sb_h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb_v.set)

    sb_v.config(command=tree.yview)
    sb_h.config(command=tree.xview)

    root.mainloop()


mainGUI()
```

Comment: Try to use `grid()` instead of `pack()`, it is easier.

Comment: @acw1668.   It doesn't work. Unless he is adding `tk.` to every widget and keyword. He is using `root= tk.TK()`

Comment: Change this `Scrollbar(resultsLabel` to `Scrollbar(results_lf`

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have seen many beginners import tkinter using both `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import *`.  Also it is not the main cause of OP issue as OP has posted images which means the application can be executed.

Comment: @acw1668. I had too many problem. So I gave up.

Comment: Change this `resultsLabel.pack` to `resultsLabel.grid` You will be able to see Label on window at the bottom. You must set this `row =1` , `row=1` and `row=2. Instead of using pack()

Comment: It is not recommended to use a `Label` widget as the parent of the treeview and the scrollbars.  Use `Frame` widget instead.

Answer (score 1):

When using `pack`, the order in which you add widgets matters. `pack` will allocate an entire side of the available space for each widget that is added.

When you pack the tree on the left, the packer allocates the entire left side for that widget. That means that things added to the top, right, or bottom will all be to the right of what was packed to the left. So, when you later pack the horizontal scrollbar it will be to the right of everything that is on the left.

The simple solution is to pack the two scrollbars before packing the tree. Personally I find it best to group together all calls to `pack` or `place` for children with a common parent. It makes visualizing the layout easier, and makes it easier to make changes like this.

So, if you move all of the calls to `pack` for these three widgets to the end of the function, it should look like this:

```
sb_v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
sb_h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.pack(side=LEFT)
```

For an answer with images that describe how the packer works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390278/tkinter-pack-method-confusion/57396569#57396569) to the question [Tkinter pack method confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390278/tkinter-pack-method-confusion)

Comment: Label is not visible. It is hidden behind treeview.

Comment: there is any way to add checkbox to each row?

Comment: @gvd: the treeview doesn't support inserting widgets. However, you can insert images so you can add an image of an unchecked checkbox. When the user clicks on it  you can toggle between checked and unchecked images.

Comment: @BryanOakley do you have any source for that..? or maybe share a simple code of it?

Answer (score 0):

- In line 29, change `results_lf.grid(row=1,` to
  `results_lf.grid(row=0,`
- In line 31, change `ttk.LabelFrame(root,` to `ttk.Label(results_lf,`
- in line 32, change to `pack` to `grid` and `row` to
  `resultsLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5,pady=0, sticky='w')`
- in line 36, `ttk.Treeview(resultsLabel`, to
  `ttk.Treeview(results_lf,`
- in line 47, change to `pack` to `grid` and `row` to
  `tree.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=10, sticky='nw')`
- In line 49, change `Scrollbar(resultsLabel` to
  `ttk.Scrollbar(results_lf,` #Vertical
- in line 50 change to `pack` to `grid` and `row` to
  `sb_v.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky='ns')`
- in line change `Scrollbar(resultsLabel,` to
  `ttk.Scrollbar(results_lf,` #HORIZPNTAL
- in line 53 change to `pack` to `grid` and `row` to sb_h.grid(row=2,column=0,
  sticky='we')

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
 
def mainGUI():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x300")
    root.title("test")
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)

    data = [["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"],
        ["this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text","this is a long text"]]


    results_lf = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Results:")
    results_lf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw')

    resultsLabel = ttk.Label(results_lf, text='hello')
    resultsLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5,pady=0, sticky='w')

    columnsHeader = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    tree = ttk.Treeview(results_lf, columns=columnsHeader, show='headings')
    tree.heading('1', text='1')
    tree.heading('2', text='2')
    tree.heading('3', text='3')
    tree.heading('4', text='4')
    tree.heading('5', text='5')
    tree.heading('6', text='6')


    for line in data:
        tree.insert('', tk.END, values=line)
    tree.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=10, sticky='nw')

    sb_v = ttk.Scrollbar(results_lf, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    sb_v.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky='ns')

    sb_h = ttk.Scrollbar(results_lf, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    sb_h.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky='we')
    

    tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb_v.set)

    sb_v.config(command=tree.yview)
    sb_h.config(command=tree.xview)

    root.mainloop()


mainGUI()
```

Screenshot: you `Label` is visible on top left:

[image]

Comment: there is any way to add checkbox to each row?

Comment: Use tree.insert

Comment: cant insert checkbox..