# How to make two buttons in same line using the pack method in tkinter (python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I want to make two buttons at the bottom of my table in python by using tkinter, one on the right and one on the left
How do I do this using the method pack?
Because the pack method has four directions, the buttons are placed under each other

```
quit = Button(text="Quit",font=("Segoe Script", 11), height=1, width=9, bg="indian red")
quit.pack(side="bottom")
restart = Button(text="Restart", font=("Segoe Script", 11), height=1, width=9, bg='indian red')
restart.pack(side="bottom")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `side=“left”` or `side=“right”`, though it’s a bit more complicated if you have more than just two widgets. In your case you should add a frame at the bottom, then put the buttons in the frame.

For a visual example of how `pack` works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390278/tkinter-pack-method-confusion/57396569#57396569)