# I want a tkinter button in python to change its position by resizing the window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

I made a desktop app using Tkinter Python and I had a problem with the positions of the button, especially the exit button, I am using "pack" as shown in the following imgs:

[image: the right position]

[image: Here is the problem]

I've tried to change the default size of the window and I searched in google and I find all solutions aren't using "pack"

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

root = Tk()
root.title("Marwan Translator")
root.iconbitmap("E:\Marwan\PROGRAMMING\pyProjects\#11 Marwan Translator\icon -.ico")

#Translation Function
def f_translation():
        try:
                global translated_text 
                translated_text = GoogleTranslator(source=t_from.get(),target=t_to.get()).translate(t_text.get())
                l_translation = Label(root, text=translated_text,fg="orange",font=('Times New Roman',15)).pack()
                
                
                

        except:
                e_except =Label(root,text="The language is not correct, Please enter the correct language",
                                font=('Times New Roman',15)).pack()

        


#Welcoming
e_title = Label(text="""Welcome To the best Translator
        MarwanTranslator          """, 
                bg= 'light blue',
                fg='red',
                borderwidth=10,
                width=40,
                height=3,
                font=('Times New Roman',25)).pack()
#Enter the languages
e_lang = Label(text="Please! Enter The languages", 
                fg='blue',
                bg='light green',
                borderwidth=10,
                width=30,
                height=1,
                font=('Times New Roman',10)).pack()

#The from language
t_fro = Label(text="From:",fg="purple",font=('Times New Roman',18)).pack()
t_from = Entry(root,width=10,borderwidth=3)
t_from.pack()

#The to language
t_too = Label(text="To:",fg="purple",font=('Times New Roman',18)).pack()
t_to = Entry(root,width=10,borderwidth=3)
t_to.pack()


#Take the text
e_text = Label(root,text="Please! Enter The Text:",fg="green",font=('Times New Roman',15)).pack()
t_text = Entry(root, width=70, borderwidth=6)
t_text.pack()


#Translated button
b_translate = Button(root,
                     text="Translate..",
                     padx=10, pady=5,
                     font=('Times New Roman',10),fg="red",bg="light blue",
                     command=f_translation).pack()

#Returning the translated text
e_translated = Label(root, text="Here Is The Translation:",fg="blue",font=('Times New Roman',15)).pack()

#Exit Button
buttonExit = Button(root,width=10,text="Exit",command=root.quit,bg='yellow').pack(side=RIGHT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will need to show your code in order for us to help.

Comment: _How_ are you using `pack`? Did you instruct it to be at the bottom of the window? Is it in the root window or are there other frames? If there are other frames, how did you pack them?

Comment: @AKX Sorry I didn't recognize that

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390278/tkinter-pack-method-confusion/57396569#57396569) and see if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `anchor="s"` to `.pack(...)` in order to put the button at the bottom of the window:

```py
buttonExit = Button(root, width=10, text="Exit", command=root.quit, bg='yellow')
buttonExit.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor="s")
```

Note also that you need to call `.pack(...)` in another line if you want to reference `buttonExit` later.